# How can I parse a String to Uri?

Tags: java, android, ringtonemanager

How do I parse an mp3 music (which is in `String` format) to Uri and play it using the `RingtoneManager`? Any suggestions

**Edit:** I've tried something like the following, where *item1* is in `String` format. But the music doesn't play when I run the app.

```
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    };
    Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            null);

    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        songs.add(cursor.getString(0));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, songs);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
             . 
             .
             .
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    item1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      }
              . 
              .
    Uri par=Uri.parse(item1);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM,par);
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,par);
                   .
                   .
                   .

    ringtone.play();
```

Comment: Are you sure `item1` is a valid *ringtone* URI?

Comment: Yes, its the selected mp3 music from the spinner converted into `String`

Comment: I don't think `item1` is a string/ uri

Comment: How can you say that?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a valid Uri, use [`Uri.parse()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/**
 * Creates a Uri which parses the given encoded URI string.
 *
 * @param uriString an RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI
 * @throws NullPointerException if uriString is null
 * @return Uri for this given uri string
 */
public static Uri parse(String uriString) {
    return new StringUri(uriString);
}
```